# Velocity variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to build some velocity variables in a SQLite database. I start with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  grp TEXT,
  ts NUMERIC
);
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO exclusions VALUES (
  '1751d4ad-0690-44d7-a13d-1106f48c7761',
  'A',
  STRFTIME ('%s', '2016-01-01 00:00:00')
);
-- ...
END TRANSACTION;
CREATE INDEX grp ON transactions (grp, ts);
```

Then for each `id` I want to see how many in the same `grp` have happened in the last x seconds. For this I do a self-join that just runs forever.

```
CREATE TABLE v_grp (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  count_1m NUMERIC,
  count_7m NUMERIC,
  count_40m NUMERIC,
  count_4h NUMERIC,
  count_1d NUMERIC,
  count_1w NUMERIC
);
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO v_grp
  SELECT
    tx1.id AS id,
    SUM (CASE WHEN tx1.ts - tx2.ts <= 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_1m,
    SUM (CASE WHEN tx1.ts - tx2.ts <= 420 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_7m,
    SUM (CASE WHEN tx1.ts - tx2.ts <= 2400 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_40m,
    SUM (CASE WHEN tx1.ts - tx2.ts <= 14400 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_4h,
    SUM (CASE WHEN tx1.ts - tx2.ts <= 86400 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_1d,
    SUM (CASE WHEN tx1.ts - tx2.ts <= 604800 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_1w
  FROM transactions as tx1
  JOIN transactions as tx2 ON
    tx1.grp = tx2.grp
    AND tx1.ts > tx2.ts
    AND tx1.ts <= tx2.ts + 604800
  GROUP BY tx1.id
;
END TRANSACTION;
```

I thought this would be manageable given that I have 13M transactions spreading over 1 year and there are 6k groups (largest one is 10% of transactions, 10th largest is 1%).

Is there any way I could make this run faster, e.g., better indexing or improved select?

Comment: SQLite is not very good for this sort of computation.  Either do the calculation externally (by reading the data from the table in order) or switch to a more powerful database.

Comment: What database would allow me to perform this efficiently and using what syntax?

Comment: . . Basically, one fundamental idea here is cumulative sums.  Any database would help; most support window functions (and MySQL supports variables in the `SELECT`).  You might want to use a temporary table, but once again, SQLite does support the cumulative sum, which is critical for this.  Postgres is a very powerful free database.